# How to switch from VS9 to VS10 for NMake with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, compiler-construction, cmake

On my computer I have both VS9 and VS10 for testing purpose.
When I configure my project with VS9 or VS10 I have no problem with CMake.

Now I want to generate a project with NMake but during the configuration it takes VS9 as default C compiler and CXX compiler and I want VS10.

Anyone has an idea how I can perform such thing ?

i.e.

I want to switch from

```
Projects>cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
...
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
```

to

```
Projects>cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
...
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
10/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
10/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
...
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 10/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studi
o 10/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
```

Thanks :)

Comment: If you haven't already, you can try asking on the CMake mailing list. You'll probably get an answer there pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NMake Makefiles generator uses the environment of your shell. In a normal cmd Window it will fail, and you normally open up the Visual Studio shell for the version you are interested in. You can also run the appropriate vcvars. I am not near a Windows machine right now, but I would check the command prompt you are using.

Comment: Run cmake from a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" -- each version of VS has shortcuts that it installs in its "Start Menu" structure to open up a command prompt with the environment variables adjusted for that version of VS. You can get the same effect in a non-VS command prompt for VS 2010 by typing in 'call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86' -- also, change the x86 to x64 to compile as a 64-bit program.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
set CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```